# Have a selector return a value in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I was wondering if it's possible to make a selector return a value, and then set this value to some variable, if, for instance, a button is pressed.

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
let test = MyTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(sampleFunction))
//somehow, here, I wanted the selector to return the value 5, and I can access it in this code
cell.button.addGestureRecognizer(test)
```

and the code for the selector would be something like this:

```
@objc sampleFunction() -> Int{
    //do some stuff that's important when the button is pressed
    return 5
}
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Short story: You cannot return anything and you cannot pass custom parameters either.

Comment: Assuming it's in a `UIViewController`, just add a property to the class. Then set this property to the value you need within the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General answer for *Have a selector return a value in Swift?*

Yes, *a selector* is just a key for a specific existing method, so if the method returns a value, you may get the returned value invoking the selector.

But, this does not mean you can return a value from an action method.

#### Specific answer for your case

No, action methods are invoked from inside iOS, and iOS ignores the returned value. (In some cases, calling a method with return value would make your app crash.)

If you *need to set `cell.button.tag = 5`*, you may need to write it in your `sampleFunction` explicitly:

```
    @objc func sampleFunction(_ gestureRecognizer: MyTapGesture) {
        let button = gestureRecognizer.view as! UIButton
        button.tag = 5
        //...
    }
```